# jQuery mouseenter and fadeTo problems

Tags: jquery

I'm doing the codeacademy.com jQuery course to get a nice taste of jQuery before I go through the jQuery In Action book, and I've got to one part and the code doesn't work and I cant see why.

I've created a jsFiddle of it here http://jsfiddle.net/weacY/

These are the instructions from codeacademy.com:

> Great! Next, let's include our function keyword and two new actions together, mouseenter() and fadeTo().
>
> mouseenter() does what you might expect: it produces a change when your mouse enters a given HTML element. For example,
>
> $(document).ready(function() {
>       $('div').mouseenter(function() {
>           $('div').hide();
>       });
>   });
>   would hide every  on the page as soon as you mouse over one. (We'll find out how to affect just one  among many in the next lesson.) For now, we only have one , so this setup is okay.
>
> Instead of hide(), however, we'll place fadeTo() inside mouseenter(). fadeTo() takes two arguments, or inputs, between its parentheses, separated by a comma: the speed at which to fade, and the opacity (or transparency) to fade to. For example,
>
> fadeTo('fast', 0.25);
>   would quickly fade the target element to 25% of its original opacity, making it very light-colored.
>
> Using the examples above, make it so your 'div' fades to 1 (100%) opacity when your mouse enters the 'div'. Make the animation speed 'fast'. (Make sure to give fadeTo() its inputs in order—speed, then opacity.)
>
> Mouse over your 'div' to see the effect!

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Button Magic</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div><br/><strong>Click Me!</strong></div>
  <script>type="text/javascript" src="script.js"</script>
 </body>
</html>​
```

Here's the CSS:

```
div {
 height: 60px;
 width: 100px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #69D2E7;
 text-align: center;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 opacity: 0.5;
}​
```

And finally the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("div").mouseenter(function() {
  $("div").fadeTo("fast", 1);
 });
});​
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: here is the wokring fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/weacY/5/

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me what I did wrong? I'll upvote and accept your answer. EDIT - Sorry didnt see the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in JSFiddle MooTools library is set by default.
Change it to jQuery and it will work:

[image]

Comment: **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/weacY/1/.

Comment: Thanks again VisioN, hmm that's odd it must be the codeacademy.com website then.

Answer (score 3):

you don't have a jquery plugin at the top:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").mouseenter(function() {
            $("div").fadeTo("fast", 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and in your fiddle you have not selected the jQuery plugin from the left side dropdowns.

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/weacY/2/

Answer (score 2):

You were including `Mootools` instead of `jQuery` in the fiddle. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/7vTfB/) a fork of yours.

Answer (score 2):

By default MooTools library is selected in fiddle which loads mootools's js. Select jquery next to onLoad select box and it will load jquery's js.

here is the working fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/weacY/5/

include `jquery` and it will work..